# How come root directory is not detected by "lspconfig" when loading "emmet_ls" client server?

Tags: macos, neovim

After a recent update, "lspconfig" could no longer detect the client server "emmet_ls." I follow the installation process exactly as followed:

1. install client server with npm

> npm install -g emmet-ls

2. paste the following code into the config file in the following directory: "~/.config/nvim/lsp-config/language-servers.lua"

[image]

However, whenever I open up an html or css file, the following error message appears:

[image]

Has anyone ever encounter this predicament?

**Update:**

For those who shares the same predicament, here is my current solution:

```
local lspconfig = require'lspconfig'
local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').update_capabilities(vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities())
capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionItem.snippetSupport = true

lspconfig.emmet_ls.setup{ 
    capabilities = capabilities,
    filetypes = { 'html', 'css', 'scss', 'xml', 'pug', 'sass'};
    root_dir = function(fname)    
        return vim.loop.cwd()
    end,
}
```